# PuTTY: Change default SSH login directory

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, default, putty

In Windows, I use **PuTTY** to log in a Linux-based remote server via SSH.

Is is possible to **change the default directory** entry point I get to after I connect and login? (That would be a nice time saver.)

e.g. from `server/home/` to `server/home/subdir/subdir/`

Comment: better fit to superuser.com

Comment: @Svisstack Is there a way to move it there as this question has some useful answers.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

- Add `cd subdir/subdir` to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`, or
- change the home directory of the user.

Comment: To change a user's home directory: **usermod -d /path/to/dir/ username**

Comment: Well, good enought for a shared hosting service. And for this particular actuation it's almost even better, since it doesn't depend on the client config at all.

Answer (score 80):

You can also change the directory within *PuTTY* itself:

1. Configuration → Connection → SSH
2. Fill in the "*Remote command*" field with the following:

   ```
   cd subdir/subdir ; /bin/bash
   ```

Comment: But it is showing bash-3.00 but it would be great if it would show prompt like asd@/var/bbc/kj/lk$. is there any way to do this?

Comment: @bimleshsharma, for me it gives the command prompt like the following: [userName@hostName directoryName]$
So it looks like what you want. Hence, it's probably an issue with your bash configuration.

Comment: yes, i am looking for same. Without setting this remote command it is fine but after setting it is not coming in usual prompt.

Comment: I launch putty from the command line - is there a command line parameter that I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare, create a stored session with remote command and run it using `putty.exe -load "session name"`. Alternatively, you can use `-m "local file name"` parameter to load the remote command from local file name. See more here: http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.66/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline

Comment: This might count as a non-login session; at least, my configuration files didn't load. I got my normal aliases and desired start location with `. ~/.bash_profile ; cd $LOGS ; ls -ltrhG --color=always | tail -n 30 ; /bin/bash`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use screen to keep your current directory by always logging into the same screen session.

Add the screen command with parameters to your putty saved session under SSH>Remote Command.
See the screen documentation for which parameters to use.

```
screen -R -O -t mysession -S mysession -f
```

Comment: I launch putty from the command line - is there a command line parameter that I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on a lot of things. Mainly the server operating system. Most SSH servers run Linux or Unix of some flavor. When you connect via any method of remote text login (as SSH is one member of this category) such a system will automatically spawn a shell process to talk to you. That's probably "bash", and it runs various things on startup. Check out

man bash

to learn more. One of the many things you can do is cd to a subfolder.